# Is this a bug in the Facebook Javascript Login SDK?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

We can't seem to pull the user_about_me section from the Facebook Javascript login SDK. The code looks right. Our permission was approved.

We've noticed something strange where one russian account > https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJKK3.png << it will return "bio" with "about me" another USA account > https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsWd6.png << it will not return "bio".

Can't figure this one out; any help would be greatly appreciated.

`scope list (requested params):scope:'public_profile,email,user_about_me,user_birthday,user_friends,read_friendlists,user_hometown,user_education_history'
version    : 'v2.2'
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"`

Answer (score 0):

Youre permissions are NOT approved, as you can see in your first screenshot. The first screenshot was most likely made by an App Admin, the second one by an ordinary user without a role in the App.

If it is really "approved" and still not working, you should file a bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: That's what would make sense but http://d.pr/i/wcGr see here it says the it IS in fact approved. :(

Comment: well, that is one permission, and you ask for a lot more. and that error message only pops up for app admins. it a permission still does not work after getting it approved, file a bug. i´ve added that information to my answer.